# How can you center a swf object?

Tags: html, css, flash

My swf is responsive so it's hard to center, I'm hoping to find and easy way to do that. Can object act like an img tag and be centered in css? I tested that theory but no luck. How would I make this code center? Do I have an alternative that can be responsive and centered?

It looks like this: 
[image]

What is below is not helping.
    X

Comment: How is it not centering if its responsive ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6pku1y73/?

Answer (score 1):

Try any of these alternatives

**css positioning**

`.hdiv {

        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 0;
    }
    object {
        position: absolute;
        left: 25%;
        top: 25%;
        width:50%;
        height: 50%;
        background:#000;
    }`

**flexbox approach**

`.hdiv {

        display:flex;
        justify-content:center;
        align-items:center;
        height:100vh;
    }
    object {

       background:#000;
       width:50%;
       height:50%;
    }`

note that you need to prefix the flexbox classes for certain browsers and syntax might be different and that vh is also not supported for older browsers.

with **css transform**

`.hdiv {

        position: absolute;
        top: 50%; left: 50%;

        background: #000;
        transform: translate(-50%,-50%);

    }`

Comment: just don't try resizing the window in Chrome if you expect the content to be fluid... not since 2013...